# Why does setting a transition on a class with checked have absolutely no effect?

Tags: css, tabs, css-transitions

I tried to create JavaScript-less tabs. 
That worked, but now I want to have a CSS-transition like on https://web.dev/articles/building/a-tabs-component

there it does it with

```
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

I wanted to just fade-in and fade-out the tab with opacity. 
But that doesn't work, and I have no idea why.
What's the matter ? 
I don't quite understand why this doesn't work, and consequently, i can't fix it.

I tried setting transition on opacity, display, with or without ease-in/out and it simply does not change at all ...

I also tried with `scroll-behavior: smooth;` but that has no effect either.

See my codepen snippet for a full example:
https://codepen.io/u155077/pen/oNmgLgM

**Note:** 
This is about CSS-styles. 
Please keep it 100% JavaScript-free.

```
    .rbTab
    {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 5s, display 1s;
    }




   .ContentTab
    {
        display: none;
        width: 630px;
        height: 180px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    
    .TitleTab
    {
        width: 630px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        /*background-color: #E5E5E5;*/
    }


    .rbTab
    {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;

    }
    
    
    .rbTab1:checked ~ .ContentTab1
    {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;


        -webkit-transition: display 2s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: display 2s ease-in;
        -o-transition: display 2s ease-in;
        transition: display 2s ease-in;
    }
    
    .rbTab2:checked ~ .ContentTab2
    {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;


        -webkit-transition: display 2s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: display 2s ease-in;
        -o-transition: display 2s ease-in;
        transition: display 2s ease-in;
    }


    .rbTab3:checked ~ .ContentTab3
    {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }


    .rbTab4:checked ~ .ContentTab4
    {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }


    .rbTab5:checked ~ .ContentTab5
    {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }


    .rbTab6:checked ~ .ContentTab6
    {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't animate the opacity of the elements the way you want when they don't have same position. What you are doing is like removing the old element and adding the new one.

You can put all Tabs in a div container, set the size of the container, change the tabs to `position: absolute;`, remove `display: none;` from the class `ContentTab` and add the transition to the class `ContentTab`.

I have modified your example: https://codepen.io/untbu/pen/zYexoGv